# Text between two image?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/CSS and trying to put text between two images. using the following code, I was able to do that. But if I have to much text, the format goes out of order as shown in `figure 1`. Can you please tell me how can I make my website look like `Figure 2`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" style="font-family:Georgia;color:black;font-size:17px;">The site provides a reference manual covering many aspects of web programming, including technologies such as HTML, XHTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript, PHP, ASP, SQL etc. W3schools presents thousands of code examples. By using the online editor provided, readers can edit the examples and execute the code experimentally.</a>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Figure 1:**
[image]

**Figure 2:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers and all the detailed. they were equally helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple fix I would use a HTML table. A single row 3 column table would work and just play with `align` in the `<td>` tag and/or pic size in `<img>` tag. There's plenty of attributes to work with that can do what you are asking. Check out http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>
    <div class="header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" style="font-family:Georgia;color:black;font-size:17px;">The site provides a reference manual covering any aspects of web programming, including technologies such as HTML, XHTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript, PHP, ASP, SQL etc. W3schools presents thousands of code examples. By using the online editor provided, readers can edit the examples and execute the code experimentally.
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
                </td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTBVR/)

You can float all the elements, wrap the text in a div and then assign a width to the div that contains the text. You could either do this with inline style, or in a separate style sheet as shown in the example.

Styles added:

```
img {
  float: left;
}
#text {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<img style="float:left" /><div style="float:left">All your text</div><img/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use table like : http://jsfiddle.net/bTSNj/

```
<div class="header">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" style="font-family:Georgia;color:black;font-size:17px;">The site provides a reference manual covering many aspects of web programming, including technologies such as HTML, XHTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript, PHP, ASP, SQL etc. W3schools presents thousands of code examples. By using the online editor provided, readers can edit the examples and execute the code experimentally.</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

or you can use div by using float like : http://jsfiddle.net/j94PP/

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  </div>
  <div class="columtext">
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" style="font-family:Georgia;color:black;font-size:17px;">The site provides a reference manual covering many aspects of web programming, including technologies such as HTML, XHTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript, PHP, ASP, SQL etc. W3schools presents thousands of code examples. By using the online editor provided, readers can edit the examples and execute the code experimentally.
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the center column dynamic in width, this works well:
http://jsfiddle.net/SNMQm/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content-right">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
    </div>

    <div class="content-left">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/pic_chart.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle">
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" style="font-family:Georgia;color:black;font-size:17px;">The site provides a reference manual covering many aspects of web programming, including technologies such as HTML, XHTML, CSS, XML, JavaScript, PHP, ASP, SQL etc. W3schools presents thousands of code examples. By using the online editor provided, readers can edit the examples and execute the code experimentally.</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-right {
    float: right;
    width: 130px;
}
.content-left {
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
}
.content {
    margin: 0 150px;
    width:100%;
}
```